# Anybody know of a public WMS out there that serves a solar terminator?

Tags: data, wms

I've just updated an app I made a few years back from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3... and I thought it'd be cool if I added in an Overlay for the solar terminator (day-night boundary).

I can't seem to locate any public WMS providers out there who offer that layer.  Anybody know of any?

Comment: Why use a WMS? take a look at http://www.lizard-tail.com/isana/lab/astro_calc/terminator.html

Comment: That library appears to be customized for use with Google Maps.  I'll need to figure out how to alter it in order to make it work with OpenLayers 3.

Comment: Were you ever able to find public WMS server that provides a solar illumination layer? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: Nope, I still haven't found anything.