# Solar Terminator (day/night boundary line) generator

Tags: qgis

I'm working on a map with an orthographic projection that requires to show the solar terminator, but I've found very difficult to draw the geometry of the day/night boundary in a specific day of the year. I'm looking for a way (or a tool) to generate (or import) this line in QGIS, and being able to determine its path for each day of the year.

The only reference I could find on the forum is this question, which has a different focus, though, and doesn't provide an answer: [Anybody know of a public WMS out there that serves a solar terminator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/215598/127712)

Below a screenshot of my draft output, where the terminator has been added manually in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: The US Naval Observatory provides a page called [Day and Night Across the Earth](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/earthview.php), which will generate static images of the earth with the day/night split. The notes at the bottom of the page say there's an API; maybe the API will provide the actual terminator line rather than just the static images. There's an [ArcGIS toolset](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6c65b0f17ffc4bfdb71f60ca64d40bcc) that does this, maybe you can dig into the javascript and figure out how the math is done.

Comment: I found some similar/related questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7546/81764 https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17184/81764 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/composition-how-to-make-a-day-and-night-world-map https://academo.org/demos/day-night-terminator/

Comment: this page has a formula to calculate the terminator: https://www.aa.quae.nl/en/antwoorden/zonpositie.html#v526